# WPF ComboBox SelectedItem is not showing its value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have created WPF application. I have a ComboBox of Colors in it. I want selected color to be as my ComboBoxItem, but it's showing 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem' instead of an item (which is my color name here) when I chose an item from ComboBox.

And here's a xaml code for a ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,330,557,0" Name="comboBox_PC_Opt" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130" IsEditable="True" SelectionChanged="comboBox_PC_Opt_SelectionChanged">
            <ComboBoxItem VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Width="15" Height="15" Margin="0,2,5,2" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Blue" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Rectangle Fill="Black" Width="15" Height="15" Margin="0,2,5,2" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Black" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ComboBoxItem></ComboBox>
```

So, how can I solve this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is using [TextSearch.TextPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textsearch.textpath(v=vs.110).aspx) attached property. You can try this code:

```
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,330,557,0" 
          Name="comboBox_PC_Opt" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130" 
          IsEditable="True" 
          SelectionChanged="comboBox_PC_Opt_SelectionChanged"
          TextSearch.TextPath="Content.Children[1].Text"
>
```

Note that the `ComboBoxItem` should contain the children (as in your code) **consistently** (so that the `Children[1]` points to the correct `TextBlock`).

**UPDATE**: If you just want to show the colored rectangle beside the color name with no need to make the ComboBox editable, you can just remove the `IsEditable="True"`.

To get the selected Color, you have to use `SelectedValuePath` to point to the `Fill.Color` of the inner `Rectangle`, of course this way the `ComboBoxItem` should always contains a `StackPanel` and this panel should contain the color `Rectangle` as the first item:

```
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,330,557,0" 
          Name="comboBox_PC_Opt" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130" 
          IsEditable="True" 
          SelectionChanged="comboBox_PC_Opt_SelectionChanged"
          TextSearch.TextPath="Content.Children[1].Text"
          SelectedValuePath="Content.Children[0].Fill.Color"
>
```

Then in behind code you can just get the `SelectedValue` like this:

```
private void comboBox_PC_Opt_SelectionChanged(object sender, 
                                              SelectionChangedEventArgs e){
    var selectedValue = ((ComboBox)e.Source).SelectedValue;
    if(selectedValue != null){
        var selectedColor = (Color)selectedValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: error is solved and i'm getting my itemname but still it doesn't show a rectangle with the itemname

Comment: @Jagdish do you really want to allow user to type in the ComboBox (editable)?

Comment: no that's not i want..i have 'rectangle' (which is filled with color) and 'color_name' besides it in the ComboBox list as in the code,  but i'm getting only color_name when i select that item. i want both the things when i select an item

Comment: @Jagdish So you can just remove the `IsEditable="True"`, it's simple indeed.

Comment: thanks a lot, it helped. If you can do me favor, one more thing i would like to know that how can i save that comboBoxItem in gridview with color_rectangle (i'm getting colorname in gridview when i select an item), but with color as in comboBox

Comment: @Jagdish see my update, you can use `SelectedValuePath` to point to the selected color.

Comment: it's possibly that you copied exactly my code, the `SelectionChanged` event handler should be `comboBox_PC_Opt_SelectionChanged` (not `combo_SelectionChanged` as I posted before).

Comment: thanks but there is already comboBox_PC_Opt_SelectionChanged in my code though it's not working

Comment: @Jagdish I made a demo on my side, it works and that's why I updated the answer (as something ***tested***). Here is [the demo](http://www.mediafire.com/download/bp5ud0uvw37luhd/ColorCombo.zip). I doubt that you have another thing to do with but it couldn't be achieved and you said it was not working. The meaning of working or not working here should answer the question ***can we get the selected color?***, if it's not what you mean, I think you have another problem which is out of the scope of this question, so posting it as a new question is better for others helping...

Comment: just try selecting a value from the ComboBox, you'll see the Background of the window is changed to the selected color.

Answer (score 1):

Set the [`DisplayMemberPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to your Combobox.

Answer (score 0):

That's way too much code when you can simply add one property. Add the tag property to the comboboxitem in XAML:

```
<Comboboxitem Tag="Blue"/>
```

Then:

```
 GetValue=ComboboxName.SelectedItem.Tag.ToString()
```

GetValue will be "Blue" instead of "System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem"

Answer (score -1):

You're getting the name of the control because the combobox doesn't know where to get the
text of the selected value.

Instead, just use other wpf controls like the headeredcontentcontrol instead where you have an header property that will be returned once the value is selected

example :

```
      <Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider 
ObjectInstance="{x:Type Colors}" 
MethodName="GetProperties" 
x:Key="colorPropertiesOdp"  />

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type HeaderedContentControl}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type HeaderedContentControl}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Content" />
                            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource colorPropertiesOdp}}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="comboBox_PC_Opt" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130" 
              >
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Color}">
                <HeaderedContentControl Header="{Binding Path=Name}">
                    <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="15" Height="15" Margin="0,2,5,2" />
                </HeaderedContentControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: It solved an error, But rectangle is being disabled when item is selected

Comment: since you set the iseditable property of the combobox to true, the box will only accepts text there. If you dont need it to be editable remove this property or set it to false and everything will work.